# Get element Id from a found element

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I'm using the Chrome driver and Selenium tools in my CodedUI tests.  I can find the element I need using the SearchProperties and a Contains operator however I need the full Id for subsequent searches.

For example I need to find an input element with Id "pm_modal_28".
This is easy enough by doing a search where Id contains "pm_modal".
I then need to parse the value "28" out of the Id that was found so I can search for the next nested element which has an Id of "dp_28".

When I use the Id property of HtmlDiv I get a NotSupportedException.  Is there anyway I can get all of the Html attributes from an Element or get the Id from an element after it has been found?

Comment: have you tried `ele.getAttribute("id");` ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this what you are after, once the control is identified, you would have all its properties to play around with. 
For example

```
        var control = new HtmlDiv ();
        control.SearchProperties.Add("Id", "MyDiv_28");

        if (!control.TryFind()) return;
        var newControl = new HtmlDiv();
        newControl.SearchProperties.Add("Id", control.Id.Split('_')[1]);
        newControl.TryFind();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    HtmlDiv myDiv = new HtmlDiv(browser);        
    //Add the search logic u want ! 
    myDiv.SearchProperties.Add("class", "ClassName");

    string onewayforID = myDiv.Id;
    string anotherWay = myDiv.GetProperty(HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.Id).ToString(); // Or u can simpy pass "Id"
```

See if that Works !